# complex model with generic types and inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I got this data model.(I am not sure if it is the best approach)
[image]

Blue blocks are Abstract classes.
Green blocks are Normal classes.

The problem I have is it:

I want to save  C, D or E object in a Sub_BaseClass variable but compiler tells me I need specify type of generic class.

```
Sub_BaseClass<?> variable;

variable = (Sub_BaseClass<?>)objct;
```

I know "objct" type will be a class of C, D or E. 
I tryed to add a Sub_BaseClass without generic type to that model before Sub_BaseClass generic, but I need to specify type of BaseClass, and then I lose the generic type in C, D and E.

How can I solve that problem?
I want/need to do something like:

```
Sub_BaseClass variable;

variable = (Sub_BaseClass)objct;
```

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to save C,D and E in a Sub_BaseClass variable you have to use generic parameters as Sub_BaseClass is generic class.

This means also that all code where the Sub_BaseClass variable is used needs to be generic code. For example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class Sub_BaseClass<T> : BaseClass
{
}

...

public void DoSomething<T>(BaseClass objct)
{
  Sub_BaseClass<T> variable;

  variable = objct as Sub_BaseClass<T>;

  ...
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But in DoSomething method I dont know the specific type. I only know the objct will be C, D or E, but not wich one of them. :/

Comment: ...then simply use `BaseClass` instead of `Sub_BaseClass<>` perhaps`?